# any value of the variable in sql query avoiding division by zero error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, divide-by-zero

I want to let users filter through results.

For this I have several dropdown lists that, by default, are set to 'All'. Values from those fields are sent to php via the POST method, and then I proceed as such:

```
if ($variable == "All") {
$variable = '%';
}
```

Then in the PDO statement, the WHERE clause goes as such:

```
WHERE field LIKE :variable
```

After that I pass the variable through an array

I get a Division by zero error which is weird because when I hard code the SQL query with

```
field LIKE '%'
```

It is all fine...

Thanks for your help, much appreciated since I have been trying out many options to solve this!

Comment: can you post some more code? Im pretty sure the error is somewhere else.

Comment: The division by zero error is almost certainly elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding lots of useless WHERE conditions like

```
field1 LIKE :value1 OR field2 LIKE :value2 OR field3 LIKE :value3
```

generating a query like

```
field1 LIKE '%' OR field2 LIKE '%' OR field3 LIKE '%actual filter%'
```

that only result in a longer execution time of your query you should write conditionals that add the filter only when set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not submit the whole code (too long!). But the problem was not what I though. Below my answer

Answer (score 0):

The division by zero error was in fact coming from the fact that my SQL query contained a CONCAT(name,'%') which works for SQL but is not well interpreted by php.

Instead, CONCAT(name, "%") works just fine...

Rookie mistake!